# how to call table-valued function in CASE expression

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want call function in case when but when i call function I get an error .
My code is :

```
s = case 
when v.IsAverage=1 then 
  isnull(avg([Value]),0) 
when v.IsCumulative=1 then  
  isnull(sum([Value]),0) 
when v.IsCumulative=0 then
  GetLastValueTest('93/.1/01','93/12/29')
```

I get this error :

> 'GetLastValueTest' is not a recognized built-in function name.

but when I call this way it works :

```
select * from GetLastValueTest('93/.1/01','93/12/29')
```

Comment: What error do you get?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> select * from GetLastValueTest('93/.1/01','93/12/29')

`GetLastValueTest` looks like a table-valued function

then correct way to use it in `case` statement is:

```
case 
when v.IsAverage=1 then isnull(avg([Value]),0) 
when v.IsCumulative=1 then   isnull(sum([Value]),0) 
when v.IsCumulative=0 then (select top 1 [ColumnName] from GetLastValueTest('93/.1/01','93/12/29'))
end
```

Answer (score 2):

Assuming your `GetLastValueTest` is scalar function - you need to specify schema explicitly, i.e. `dbo.GetLastValueTest('93/.1/01','93/12/29')` (or whatever you schema is if it different from `dbo`)

If your `GetLastValueTest` is table-valued function then you can't mix select from it with scalar values in other branches of `case`. In this case you need something like

```
when v.IsCumulative=0 
then (select top 1 some_value from dbo.GetLastValueTest('93/.1/01','93/12/29'))
```

Comment: i getting this error :Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'SELECT'.
Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 9
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'FROM'.

Comment: @PsarTak wait... is your `GetLastValueTest` table-valued function or scalar one?